# why my Application Crashes when Phone is Tilted from vertical to horizontal landscape mode

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-orientation

[image][image][image]I am in process to create a new android application with EditText component occupying my complete screen 
{ `<EditText 
android:width="fill_parent" 
android:height="fill_parent" />`}

I am assigning text to EditText component through `setText(getResources().getIdentifier("TextName","string",getPackageName()));` file dynamically according to users choice from options available in Spinner

It is all fine to execute desired output, but when i change my landscape from verticall to horzontal and vice-versa, my application crashes with annoying statement "Unforfunetly, exampleApplication has stopped"

I will be Thankful to any encouraging reply and suitable solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: copy your code here,specially onCreate

Comment: Post your logcat output.

Comment: Paste your code her I can see from logcat that you are receiving NullPointerException at line 50 in com.ex.trail.SongsActivity.onItemSelected method

Comment: public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,long arg3) {
  TextView textView = (TextView) view;
  /*50th line*/ SongName = textView.getText().toString(); 
  
  if(SongName=="- Select your song - "){
   onNothingSelected(arg0);
  }else{
   intent = new Intent(this,SongPage.class);
   temp = (String) textView.getText();
   intent.putExtra("song name",temp);
    startActivity(intent);
    textView.setText("- Select your song - ");
  } 
 }
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){
  Toast.makeText(this,"Select any song and get Lyrics", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what's happening is that when you rotate the screen, Android tries to recreate the activity in landscape mode (because you could have provided a landscape layout file).

If you don't want to have a landscape layout specifically, then add this to your `<activity></activity>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SongsActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" <!--This line-->
        android:label="SomeLabelName" />
```

This will rotate the activity without any recreation.

What exactly does this mean? Adding this tag in your activity tells Android that Configuration Changes, if any, will be handled by you explicitly, and the system need not worry about recreation. In response, the system simply rotates the view, which is sufficient in most cases.

I would still suggest that you read more of Android documentation on this. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you Awanish Raj, this detailed explanation gave me enough clarity.